# How To Get IAuthenticationManager Implementation Mapped in StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap, asp.net-identity

I'm struggling to use StructureMap and Microsoft AspNet Identity together in that I can't seem to figure out how to get an implementation of IAuthenticationManager mapped. I'm trying to explicitly map this in the DefaultRegistry per the example below.

```
   public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {

        public DefaultRegistry() {
            Scan(
                scan => {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
                });

            For<IAuthenticationManager>().Use(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
        }
   }
```

The main problem is that HttpContext.Current is always null but I'm not even sure this will work even if that isn't null. I'm a big newbie with StructureMap and with AspNet Identity so feel free to call me out on anything silly I'm doing here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like the code above is working just fine and I'm not sure why it didn't seem to be working before. I don't know what is protocol to close out the issue but I don't want anyone to think that they can't use the above for reference since it works.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a StructureMap issue per se. HttpContext.Current will only be available inside of an HTTP request in ASP.Net. If you want to use HttpContext within StructureMap, I'd suggest either being sure that you check for the null gracefully or try to switch to using the HttpContextWrapper/HttpContextBase abstraction so that you can run that code outside of ASP.Net in your tests.